# Interactive Grid[-cells] in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, user-controls, grid

I have to create a control which meets the following requirements:

- Items are displayed in **cells** of a "*table*"
- Items are **selectable**
- Items are **drag n droppable**

I have 2 approaches:

1. Using an `ItemsControl` with a `Grid` as it's `ItemsPanelTemplate`
   *Big problem: ItemsControl doesnt support selection out of the box*
2. Use a `DataGrid` (seems obscure to me, since it's "not designed for this")

Here's the `ItemsControl` I am speaking of:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5,5,5,0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Name="ItemsRack">
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowPos}" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColPos}" />
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid ShowGridLines="False">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Items are displayed in cells of a "table"

   You have a couple options:

   - Use DataGrid: It does have "cells" and provides some features for editing them. If you get to know it well, you can do even more complex stuff.
   - Create your own? This ensures you are in control of everything and know how everything works. If this is a big project, I'd go with this option. Study the DataGrid and emulate it. If you run into roadblocks, check out third-party solutions and try to learn from them.
   - Go third-party: Xceed has a free DataGrid that provides more features than the standard .NET one probably ever will. Cells are definitely present and the features are seemingly enough.

     http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/
2. Items are selectable

   - ListBox/ListView is a reasonable alternative, but probably not what you're looking for.
   - ItemsControl is limited in what it can do and does NOT support item selection.
   - DataGrid: Your best bet. Refer to first response.
3. Items are drag n droppable

   - Look into GongSolutions' drag/drop library. The rumors really are true, it works wonders.

     https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop

Keep in mind, if you decide to roll out your own DataGrid, it is no simple task. Fun, but difficult.